# Why is my code not printing answer in float?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
float div ( int a,int b, int c, float x );
int main() 
{ 
    int a,b,c,x;
    a=250;
    b=85;
    c=25;

    x=div (a,b,c,x);


   printf("%d ", x);

}
// your code goes here
float div (int a,int b, int c, float x) 
{
    x=((a-b)/c);
    return(x);

}
```

Comment: Please finx teh code., (Read as: Please fix the code)

Comment: `x` is `int` and you print it via `%d` as `int`. What did you expect?

Comment: Doesn't your compiler scream in pain when you assign a `float` return value to an `int` variable?

Comment: Not really a duplicate, because here there are other issues too.

Answer (score 0):

Because `x` is declared as `int` instead of `float`.

Your code:

```
int x;
...
printf("%d ", x);
```

What you need instead:

```
float x;
...
printf("%f ", x);
```

And your `div` function is wrong too:

```
float div (int a,int b, int c, float x) 
{
    x=((a-b)/c);  // << this will perform an integer division
    return(x);    //    and therefore x will be truncated, even if it is a float
}
```

You need this:

```
float div (int a,int b, int c, float x) 
{
    x = ( ((float)(a-b) ) / c);
    return x;   
}
```

The `(float)` before `(a-b)` is called a cast and will ensure that `(a-b)` will be treaded as a `float` number during the division by `c`.

BTW the function can be simplified, you don't need the `x` parameter:

```
float div (int a,int b, int c) 
{
    float x = ( ((float)(a-b) ) / c);
    return x;   
}
```

or even simpler:

```
float div (int a,int b, int c) 
{
    return ((float)(a-b) ) / c;
}
```

Comment: I will try. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I made a few changes as suggested, it works now.                               #include <stdio.h>
float div ( int a,int b, int c );
int main() 
{ 
 int a,b,c;
 float x;
    a=250;
    b=85;
    c=25;

    x= div (a,b,c);


   printf("%f ", x);

}

float div (int a,int b, int c) 
{
    return ((float)(a-b) ) / c;
}

Answer (score 0):

Look closely at the statement

```
   x=((a-b)/c);
```

Note the operands, they are all integers, so the integer division is performed and then, the result is converted to floating type upon assignment. You don't want that.

In case you want a floating point division, you need to make sure one of the operands are of type float/ double.

You can use a cast, like

```
  x=(((float)a-b)/c);
```

to force floating point arithmetic.

That said, in the `main()`, you **MUST** use proper conversion specifier for `float`, `%f`.

Answer (score -1):

prints out an integer:

```
    printf("%d ", x);
```

prints out an floating point number:

```
    printf("%f", x);
```

also x must be from type float

Comment: Did you test that? I expect at least a warning for using a float specifier for an int.

Comment: ye you would need to cast, forgot to mention the false type of x before. Answer edited now, thx